# UITextView does not detect touch input

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have an app with a tab bar with several tabs. I inserted a new tab with a simple`UITextView`. However, the text view does not seem to respond to touch inputs and I am not able to edit it. It just stays static with the default text and does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. It was an issue with a class returning "NO" to canBecomeFirstResponder method. What a nightmare that took me hours to realize! Anyway, thanks everybody for your time and help and so sorry for posting such a stupid problem!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both **Editable** and **Selectable** are enabled:

[image]

You can achieve this programmatically also:

```
myTextView.editable = true
myTextView.selectable = true
```

[**UITextView Class Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Both options are checked but problem stays :(

Comment: @YUNo Perhaps you have a view on top of your `UITextView`. Edit your question to include a screenshot of your Storyboard setup and any relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

From the `Attributes inspector` make sure that `User Interaction Enable` is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Select your text view and from attribute inspector make sure that `userinteraction` is enable and check other options also as screenshot.

[image]

make sure that you checked `editable` under `behavior`